# Firebase returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following problem. The code recognizes that there is something and shows all the entries, but not the content, but only displays [object object]. 
I really want to read everything that is in the category "abgeschlosseneAuftraege" and also all subcategories. But for now I try to read at least 1 entry.
I would be very grateful for help.

```
firebase.database().ref("/abgeschlosseneAuftraege").on('value', function(snapshot){
  let elm = document.getElementById("data");
  elm.innerHTML = '';

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    elm.innerHTML += childData['Accepted'];
  })
})
    getData();
```

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YA4R.jpg)

Comment: childSnapshot.val() must be returning an object. not a string.

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you get when you use an object where a string is required. So `childData['Accepted']` must be an object. What does `console.log(childData['Accepted'])` show?

Comment: @rlemon `childSnapthot.val()` has to be an object so you can use `childData['Accepted']`.

Comment: yea duh. that was a brain fart comment on my part. I meant childData.Accepted must be an object. my bad

Comment: @Barmar  elm.innerHTML += console.log(childData['Accepted']); 
elm.innerHTML + = console.log (childData ['Accepted']); shows all entries, but instead of object object it shows undefined undefinedundefined ...

Comment: Not `elm.innerHTML += console.log` just `console.log` by itself.

Comment: @Barmar that shows nothing :/

Comment: That's not possible. It should be the object that is being turned into `[object Object]`.

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot, `childSnapshot.Accepted` is an object like `{LFd7aL...: "lFd7aL..."}`

Comment: Try using `elm.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(childData.Accepted)`

Comment: @Barma 1000 Thanks! That code works. I have been working on the problem for a very long time. I'm really grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childData['Accepted'];` is an object, not a string. If you want to see a representation of it, use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
    elm.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(childData['Accepted']);
```